# Can we get the jQuery Validate error type?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin.  Is there any way to get the type of error from the jQuery form validation?  For example,

```
$('registration-form').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "This is a required field.",
            email: "This is not a valid email address"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent());
    }
});
```

I would like to place only the error message generated from a "required" error inside a "div" somewhere on the html page rather than appending it to "element.parent()".  If I can get the error type, e.g. "required" or "email" error, I can write the code to do this.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

aobs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may edit plugin easily. You can add one more parameter for each validation(see the regexes) to identify which one is caught.