# Jquery validation get error type

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin. Is there any way to get the type of error from the jQuery form validation? For example,

```
$('mform').validate({
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 40
    }
},
messages: {
    email: {
        required: "This is a required field.",
        maxlength: "Please enter less than 40 chars"
    }
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
}
});
```

I would like to place only the error message generated from a "required" error inside a "div" somewhere on the html page rather than appending it to "element.parent()". If I can get the error type, e.g. "required" or "maxlength" error, I can write the code to do this.

[Can we get the jQuery Validate error type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075804)

The above question didn't mention what parameters to be added. So asking again.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you just copy and paste [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12075804/218196) (basically)?

Comment: That answer is too generic for me.It didnt give me what parameters i can add/use to get the error type. So I asked again. sorry though.

Comment: Yes, but just copy and pasting the question is not very beneficial. You should have described the problem in your own words, link to the other question and explain why it was not helpful for you. *edit:* as you just did.

Comment: Aye. Guess I was curious to ask before I provide full info.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  Short answer:

**What you are requesting simply cannot be done with this plugin.**  *(this is also the very rare occasion where something, that can not be done by default, also should probably not be done at all.)*

**1)**  Write your own custom plugin using this plugin as your starting point.  Make a serious attempt at doing this yourself, then come back to SO and post a new, more detailed, question when you get stuck.

**2)**  Find a plugin that already does what you want.  However, I doubt one exists since the requested option is not something people would normally want.  A consistent and uniform user experience means that all error messages are handled the same, regardless of the rule that triggered it.

---

original answer follows...

---

I suppose you could use the `errorPlacement` callback function like this...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (error.text().indexOf("required") !== -1) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    } else {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/VVaKV/**

However, this solution has some flaws since it only handles the *initial* placement of the `label` on the very first error message.  All subsequent messages will be in the same initial position since the plugin only shows/hides the message `label` after its creation.  (It could work well in situations where there's only one type of message on each field.)

I don't think any of the [other callback functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) will work any better since what you want was not built into this plugin.  *(Probably because most people believe it's less confusing to the user when all errors have a consistently uniform appearance, IMO.)*

I've answered a few hundred SO questions about this plugin and yours is the first, that I've encountered, requesting to be able to handle one type of error message differently than another.  Most people just want a more consistent user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot use this. I want to get the type of the error rather than the text in the error message. Specifically I need to know error types other than required types.

Comment: @ChandraZ, then what you want makes no sense as far as this plugin is concerned.  It cannot be done without re-writing the plugin yourself.

Comment: @ChandraZ, This is a very complex plugin and I suggest you first make an attempt yourself and then come back and post a new question if/when you get stuck.  However, I urge against this for the reasons of _"inconsistent user experience"_ I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var message = $(error).text(); 

    // here message is your error text message
}
```